# batch if variable is less than variable doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Have I done something wrong or why this isn't working? I am quite new with batch. It says "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

```
if %nm1% lss %nm2% (
    echo    voitit:%voitat%
    set /p "tupla=Voitonmaksu.1 tuplaus.2 (1/2)."
)
if %nm1%==%nm2% (
    set /a voitat=%voitat% / 2
    echo    voitit:%voitat%
    set /a voitot=%voitot% + %voitat%
    pause
    goto peli
)
if %nm2% lss %nm1%(
    echo    voitit:0
    pause
    goto peli
)
if %tupla%==1 (
    set /a voitot=%voitot% + %voitat%
    pause
    goto peli
)
if %tupla%==2 goto tuplaus
```

Comment: I would suggest instead of `set /a voitat=%voitat% / 2` & `set /a voitot=%voitot% + %voitat%` you use, `Set/A voitat/=2` & `Set/A voitot+=voitat` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set /a voitat=%voitat% / 2
set /a voitot=%voitot% + %voitat%
```

These commands won't work as expected because of `delayedexpansion` (many many SO articles on this - use the `search` facility in the top bar)

**BUT** since you are using `set/a` - the syntax allows the variables to be expressed "nude" - without the `%` delimiters, when the `delayedexpansion` quirk becomes irrelevant (but you should read up on it anyway - to obviate the inevitable follow-up question.)

```
if %nm2% lss %nm1%(
```

There must be a space between `%nm1%` and `(`

If either argument is non-numeric (probably not, given their names) then the arguments must be "quoted" (applies to *any* `if` where the arguments *may* contain spaces)

Comment: @aschipfl - You can't use quotes if you want to do a numeric comparison. The simplest protection against empty (undefined) variables in an IF statement is to use delayed expansion.

Comment: @dbenham, I agree; actually I was just referring to the last sentence of the answer...